# Symfony remember me login datetime needed

Tags: php, symfony

For my web application I need to know when a user logged in, this works fine through the normal login form. I created an AuthenticationHandler that stores the current datetime in the user object on success. But when the user decides to use the "remember me" functionality this doesn't work the next time it "logs in", it doesnt pass the onAuthenticationSuccess function.

Does anyone know of a method where i could save the login datetime on a "remember me" login. Or can someone tell me if i can override a method that reads the remember me cookie, so I could do it from there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a listner

service.yml

```
services:
    login_listener:
        class: 'Acme\YourBundle\Listener\LoginListener'
        arguments: ['@security.context', '@doctrine']
        tags:
            - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'security.interactive_login' }
```

Your Listner Class

```
<?php

namespace Acme\YourBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry as Doctrine;


class LoginListener
{
    private $securityContext;
    private $em;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param SecurityContext $securityContext
     * @param Doctrine        $doctrine
     */
    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext, Doctrine $doctrine)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->em              = $doctrine->getEntityManager();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param InteractiveLoginEvent $event
     */
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        if ($this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            // here your code
        }elseif ($this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
            // here your code
        }

    }
}
```

- IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED - automatically assigned to a user who
  was authenticated via a remember me cookie.
- IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY - automatically assigned to a user that has
  provided their login details during the current session.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html

Comment: For reference, this `SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN` event is dispatched in the `handle()` function of the `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\RememberMeListener`

Comment: ah awesome, thanks! I'm going to try this later today and i'll accept your answer if it works.